# AutoMapper setting all properties to NULL on destination

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

In an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web API, I am trying to map an entity model to a DTO using AutoMapper.

The entity model:

```
namespace InspectionsData.Models
{
    [Table("property")]
    public class Property
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("property_id")]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Column("show_inventory")]
        public bool ShowInventory { get; set; }

        [Column("latitude")]
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }

        [Column("longitude")]
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }

        [Column("property_type_id")]
        public int? PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyTypeId")]        
        [Display(Name = "Property Type")]
        public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

        [Column("inspection_frequency_id")]
        public int? InspectionFrequencyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("InspectionFrequencyId")]        
        [Display(Name = "Inspection Frequency")]
        public InspectionFrequency InspectionFrequency { get; set; }

        [Column("group_id")]
        public int? GroupId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
        [Display(Name = "Group")]
        public Group Group { get; set; }

        [Column("added_by_id")]
        public int? AddedById { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AddedById")]
        [Display(Name = "Added By")]
        public virtual User AddedBy { get; set; }

        [Column("added_date")]
        [Display(Name = "Added Date")]
        public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

        [Column("deleted_by_id")]
        public int? DeletedById { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DeletedById")]
        [Display(Name = "Deleted By")]
        public virtual User DeletedBy { get; set; }

        [Column("deleted_date")]
        [Display(Name = "Deleted Date")]
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

and the DTO:

```
namespace InspectionsData.DTOs
{
    public class PropertyDto
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public bool ShowInventory { get; set; }
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
        public InspectionFrequency InspectionFrequency { get; set; }
        public DateTime NextInspectionDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The mapping is done in a configuration file:

```
public class AutoMapperProfileConfiguration : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfileConfiguration()
    {
        // Add as many of these lines as you need to map your objects
        var map = CreateMap<Property, PropertyDto>();
        map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.ShowInventory, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ShowInventory));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Latitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Latitude));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Longitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Longitude));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropertyType));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.InspectionFrequency, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InspectionFrequency));
    }    
}
```

And the setting up of AutoMapper in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfileConfiguration());
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);
}
```

In my controller action, I execute the mapping:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProperty()
    {
            var properties = _context.Property
                .Include(t => t.PropertyType)
                .Include(f => f.InspectionFrequency)
                .Where(a => a.DeletedDate == null && a.GroupId == 1);


            var propertiesDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PropertyDto>>(properties);

            return Ok(propertiesDto);
        }
```

It doesn't give an error, but all the properties in all the objects in the propertiesDto list are default values (NULL for objects and nullable types, FALSE for booleans, 0 for integers, etc.) Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You're not using AM the way it's designed to be used and that's getting you into trouble. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1570#issuecomment-235515886).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the following line

```
map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

is letting AM ignore all member mappings, including the ones you have configured explicitly.

Simply use `ForAllOtherMembers` instead:

```
map.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```